# How to show progress bar twice on one request (with Batch API)

Tags: 8

I have a custom form which handles two different process after submission, let's say

- Process 1: removing all article nodes
- Process 2: importing article nodes from csv.

The problem is that each process have to have its own progress bar.So, it should look like:

- Form submitted
- Progress bar for process 1 starts(0%)
- Progress bar for process 1 finishes(100%)
- Progress bar for process 2 starts(0%)
- Progress bar for process 2 finishes(100%)
- Redirect to form

If I add `batch_set()` twice in submission handler, both process are executed but progress bar appears only once.

```
// Create two different batches.

public static function getBatch1() {
    $batch_builder = new BatchBuilder();
    $batch_builder->setTitle('Process 1')
    $batch_builder->addOperation(
        [self::class, 'processCallback1'],
      );
    return $batch_builder->toArray();
  }

public static function getBatch2() {
    $batch_builder = new BatchBuilder();
    $batch_builder->setTitle('Process 2')
    $batch_builder->addOperation(
        [self::class, 'processCallback2'],
      );
    return $batch_builder->toArray();
  }
```

```
// Custom form submission handler.
public function submitForm() {
 batch_set(MyBatchClass::getBatch1());
 batch_set(MyBatchClass::getBatch2());
}
```

It actually looks like:

- Form submitted
- Progress bar for process 1 starts(0%)
- Progress bar for process 1 finishes(100%) <- process 2 is also finished in background
- Redirect to form

How can I restart the progress bar when the second process begins?

Comment: Try implementing each Batch API process in its own class.

Comment: @863, could you share code for the batch callbacks processCallback1, processCallback2?